# BibTeX key case issue in section title

Tags: macros, bibtex, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` and I am trying to put publication titles into `section` titles. However, when I use `\citefield` or similar commands within a `section` command, I cannot use the same reference anymore anywhere else with `citefield` or `citep`. The reason seems to be that the `section` command somehow converts the BibTeX key into lower case. When I try to use `citefield` (or `citep`) anywhere else, I get the following error:

```
BibTeX Case mismatch error between cite keys bentley99a and Bentley99a : \citation{bentley99a
```

In my original project, I have a rather large .bib file where no BibTeX key is lower case, so I am trying to find a way to keep the `section` command from lower-casing the BibTeX key that I pass it. I tried to define a new command which I hoped would expand the publication title like this:

```
\newcommand\includepub[1]{%
  \edef\temptitle{\citefield{#1}{title}}
  \section{\temptitle} \label{sec:pub-#1}
  ...%
}
```

However, the issue still occurs when using, e.g., `\includepub{Bentley99a}`. How can I pass the raw publication title to the `section` command so that it does not use a lower-case version of the BibTeX key? Alternatively, how can I get the `section` command to not modify the BibTeX key that is processed?

Note for reproducing: Use the `classicthesis` style with all of its files, change the BibTeX key of the first publication from `bentley:1999` to `Bentley99a` and put `\section{\citefield{Bentley99a}{title}}` and `\citefield{Bentley99a}{title}` anywhere into any of the chapters. I tried to reproduce the issue without `classicthesis` with several combinations of packages and options, but failed to do so, unfortunately. I can share a full MWE on Overleaf if desired.

Comment: It would be great if you could share an MWE, but please don't share an Overleaf link, make the MWE so small that you can included the code directly in the question. (`classicthesis` is on CTAN, so that shouldn't be an issue.)

Comment: @moewe: I tried to isolate a MWE, but did not succeed. Using only `classicthesis.sty`, `biblatex`, `hyperref` and all of the respective settings, the issue cannot be reproduced. At the moment, I can only reproduce it with the full `classicthesis` template with all of its files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to protect the entry with `\NoCaseChange` but be aware that this also prevent the title to be printed in lower case small caps. Imho it would be easier not to use the \citation command here and to type the title directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{\protect\NoCaseChange{\citefield{Entry}{title}}}

\citefield{Entry}{title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works in principle, but a change of the headings is an undesired side effect. Is there any other workaround to force the expansion of the title before the section command?

Comment: No, biblatex commands are not expandable. Even without the additional problem with your uppercase entry key it wouldn't work. You would need a special font which has only lowercase letters to get this working. It is certainly less trouble to simply write the title directly.